# How to compare columns that have variable text in Excel across all variables number of sheets then sum the matchs?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created VBA code which can run across all the sheets in a workbook, and it doesn't matter how many sheets there are. The code will run correctly whether there is 3 sheets or 100 sheets. What I'm trying to work out is how to compare columns that have variable text and numbers across all sheets (regardless of how many sheets there are), and then sum the matched ones?

```
Dim x As Long

Sheets.Select
' Then code which will go across all sheets 

'' Or the following code which will go across all sheets except the main master sheet 

    For x = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(x).Name <> "Main Master Sheet" Then Sheets(x).Select Replace:=False
    Next x
```

Comment: This is unclear. How do you define a match and what does it mean to sum them? Summing numbers makes sense but you explicitly talk about *text* or numbers. How is text to be summed?

Answer (score 0):

If the text overall the workbook is matched will count how many have matched and then sum them up. 
I can use two-cells (if match =1 ) them sum the ones which will give me the total.